# Saving Flag attribute enum in settings file

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums, settings

I am attempting to save a series of booleans in a settings.cs file. Here is my current save method.

```
    private void SaveConfiguration()
    {
        VisibilitySwitchesFlags VisibilitySwitchesSaves = 0;

        if (_menu.TreeItemDictionary[VisibilityItems.ReferenceLines].Checked)
        VisibilitySwitchesSaves = VisibilitySwitchesFlags.ReferenceLinesChecked;

        if (_menu.TreeItemDictionary[VisibilityItems.ShowProfilePoints].Checked)
        VisibilitySwitchesSaves = VisibilitySwitchesFlags.ShowProfilePointsChecked;

        Settings.Default.VisibilityViewStates = (int)VisibilitySwitchesSaves;//convert to int
        Settings.Default.Save();
     }
```

and here is my Load method:

```
  private void LoadConfiguration()
  {
    VisibilitySwitchesFlags flags =(VisibilitySwitchesFlags)Settings.Default.VisibilityViewStates;

    _menu.TreeItemDictionary[VisibilityItems.ReferenceLines].Checked = flags.HasFlag(VisibilitySwitchesFlags.ReferenceLinesChecked);
    _menu.TreeItemDictionary[VisibilityItems.ShowProfilePoints].Checked = flags.HasFlag(VisibilitySwitchesFlags.ShowProfilePointsChecked);
  }
```

After the load, It appears that my save is unsuccessful. Is there a mistake in my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a flag enum you need to set it differently.

For example:

```
VisibilitySwitchesSaves |= VisibilitySwitchesFlags.ReferenceLinesChecked;
```